# Breaking from a loop in list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a simple task of selecting all elements from a list (sorted in descending order) that lie above a given element.
i.e.

```
X=[32,28,26,21,14,11,8,6,3]
Threshold=12
Result=[32,28,26,21,14]
```

What I did initially was something simple like

```
FullList=[x for x in FullList if x>=Threshold]
```

However, since the list is sorted, I can (and need to) break in between.

After much head banging and a beautiful tutorial [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1554/four-tricks-for-comprehensions-in-python), I finally came up with the following solution.

```
 def stopIteration():
      raise StopIteration

 FullList=list(x if x>=Threshold else stopIteration() for x in FullList )
```

However, when I write the following statement, it gives me a syntax error:

```
FullList=list(x if x>=Threshold else raise StopIteration for x in FullList )
```

What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: `x if x>=Threshold else raise StopIteration` is not a valid expression because `raise StopIteration` does not have a value, so it can't be added to a list. Any reason you don't just use a loop for this?

Comment: You should have read the tutorial you referred to more carefully. It answers your specific question (not a valid expression) and mentions using itertools.takewhile as well as a somewhat hackish (IMO) method using the user defined function stopif() to raise StopIteration within the implicit comprehension loop -- It really is a pretty good tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`raise` is a statement, but inside another statement you can only use expressions.

Also, why not use [`itertools.takewhile`?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

```
full_list = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x >= threshold, full_list))
```